# Error in solving a system of nonlinear equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

What is the problem with this code?

```
function F = Final_Project_2(x)
 F = [(1/x(1)) + (1/x(2))- (2/(7*x(3)));
       (x(3)+2*x(4))*(15*x(2))/((x(1)+x(2))*x(3)-0.7/x(3))-14;
       (x(3)*((0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)))/(x(3)+(0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)) -20;
       ((0.576*x(2)*x(3)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27*x(4)/x(3))-100];
```

And here is the workspace code:

```
x0 = [1; 1; 1; 1];           % Make a starting guess at the solution
options=optimset('Display','iter');   % Option to display output
[x,fval] = fsolve(@Final_Project_2,x0,options)  % Call optimizer
??? Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in ==> Final_Project_2 at 5
F = [(1/x(1)) + (1/x(2))- (2/(7*x(3)));

Error in ==> fsolve at 254
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot
    continue.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab fails to concatenate the following array:

```
F = [(1/x(1)) + (1/x(2))- (2/(7*x(3)));
       (x(3)+2*x(4))*(15*x(2))/((x(1)+x(2))*x(3)-0.7/x(3))-14;
       (x(3)*((0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)))/(x(3)+(0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)) -20;
       ((0.576*x(2)*x(3)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27*x(4)/x(3))-100];
```

The problem occurs in the third row where the last `-20` is interpreted as a single value in a vector rather than a part of the term you are calculating. To demonstrate this, you can bracket each row of this array and have a look at the results:

```
x = [1 2 3 4]; % just for demonstration purpuse

[(1/x(1)) + (1/x(2))- (2/(7*x(3)));]
[       (x(3)+2*x(4))*(15*x(2))/((x(1)+x(2))*x(3)-0.7/x(3))-14;]
[       (x(3)*((0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)))/(x(3)+(0.576*x(2)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27/x(3)) - 20;]
[       ((0.576*x(2)*x(3)/(x(1)+x(2))*x(3)) - 0.27*x(4)/x(3))-100]
```

This results in

```
ans =
    1.4048

ans =
   23.6426

ans =
    0.7843  -20.0000

ans =
  -96.9040
```

Please note the 1x2 vector in the third row.

To solve your problem, either put more emphasis on placing spaces in your calculation (i.e., omit all spaces, or write `- 20` instead of `-20` in your example), or put everything that belongs to one term in parentheses.

Comment: Thats it. I wonder why MATLAB error description didn't notice it.  How can I solve for positive values?

Comment: It did. In the snipped you posted it clearly said: "CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.".

Comment: I mean x(1) to x(4) should be positive

Comment: You want to bound x to positive values? That's a whole different topic. I'd suggest to ask a new question.